# Error while implementing generic Max method

Tags: c#

I am implementing a generic method to get Max value from list like,

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);
        list.Add(3);
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Max(list);
    }

    public T Max<T>(List<T> values) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        T max = values[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < values.Count; i++)
            if (values[i].CompareTo(max) > 0)
                max = values[i];
        return max;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error when calling `Max` method which is:

> The type 'object' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Program.Max(List)'.There is no implicit reference conversion from 'object' to 'System.IComparable'.

Confused!!!

Any help???

Comment: Have you considered adding `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code, to use the Max method available in Linq? It still wouldn't work on `List<object>`, since you need to be able to compare the items in the list, but if you change it to `List<int>` it would work.

Answer (score 2):

You have a generic constraint in the `T` argument that says `T` must implement `IComparable<T>` and you are passing `object` as the generic type argument, the type is automatically inferred because you have a `List<object>`, so `p.Max(list)` is equivalent to `p.Max<object>(list)`.

But the `object` class does not implement `IComparable<T>` hence you get the error.

You can change the type to `int` instead which implements `IComparable<T>`:

```
var list = new List<int>();
```

Comment: Actually currently I am getting the data with type object. And sometimes Date and other data types can also be present. That's why the generic method. In such cases, I can't change the types into one specific type.

Comment: that is not how generics work. if type is not known at compile time you can't call a generic method like this. you would have to use reflection. it would have been helpful if you explained your **actual** problem in the question.

Comment: Right, but as Selman Genç, you actually can't do it with "object" objects, because they are not inherently comparable. Anything in your list m0ust implement IComparable. If you were to use a list of Alligator objects, which do not implement IComparable, they would not have a `CompareTo` method. In other words, the problem has less to do with your Max method and more to do with the test data you are sending. The list you pass must match the criteria you indicate (T must be IComparable)